# how to pass select query to js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to replace this code from:

```js
var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.people = ko.observableArray([
        { firstName: 'James', lastName: 'Smith', age: 38 },
        { firstName: 'Susan', lastName: 'Smith', age: 36 },
        { firstName: 'Jeremy', lastName: 'Smith', age: 10 },
        { firstName: 'Megan', lastName: 'Smith', age: 7 },
        { firstName: 'James', lastName: 'Jones', age: 40 },
        { firstName: 'Martha', lastName: 'Jones', age: 36 },
        { firstName: 'Peggy', lastName: 'Jones', age: 10 }
    ]);
```

with select sql query that i used in PHP

```html
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ");
while($fak = mysql_fetch_array($result)){}
```

the result will echo in this code

```html
<table>
<thead>
    <tr data-bind="foreach: headers">
        <th data-bind="click: $parent.sort, text: title"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: filteredPeople">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: lastName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: age"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

help please
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass the results of the select query to JavaScript, which is what you say in the title of your question, this is how you could do that based on the sample JS you provided:

```
<?php

$jsArr = '';
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table xxxx");
$rowCount = mysql_num_rows($result);
$i = 0;
while($fak = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $i++;
    $jsArr .= '{firstName:\'' . $fak["firstName"] . '\',lastName:\'' . $fak["lastName"] . '\',age:' . $fak["age"] . '}';
    if ($i<$rowCount) { $jsArr .= ','; } // Add comma after all but the final row
}

?>

var viewModel = function() {

    var self = this;
    self.people = ko.observableArray([<?php echo $jsArr; ?>]);

});
```

It looks like you've already got something that inserts the JavaScript data into the HTML.

Comment: thank you, it working just swapped the Square Bracket 
from )] to ])
ko.observableArray([<?php echo $jsArr; ?>])

Comment: Good catch!  I've updated the brackets in my answer.  I should have mentioned there might be typos - I had to do that one in notepad and didn't have an IDE available to check the syntax.  Glad it worked for you.